# Where should I add "customElemet:true" in Svelte Kit?

Tags: element, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to create a custom element in Svelte Kit like so `<svelte:options tag="my-element" />`  in the docs is a line saying that you have to add this line `customElemet:true` but where? Svelte Kit doesn't have `rollup.config.js` with plugins but `svelte.config.js` without plugins.

Do you know where to add it in Svelte Kit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the `svelte.config.js` you can add the key `compilerOptions` to the `config` object. Inside that key create a new object that sets the key `customElement` with the value `true`, i.e.:

```js
// svelte.config.js

// imports ...

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    compilerOptions: {
        customElement: true
        // other compiler options ...
    },

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        // other kit options ...
    },

    // other config options ...
};

export default config;
```

Comment: I am following a book (paid) and it said to add the compilerOptions statement in vite.config.js`and NOT in the correct file > *svelte.config.js* so thanks for pointing to the correct file!